# Cant add table to database via linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a table to an existing database in a linked server, but getting:

> The object name 'name.mycompany.com.DataAg.dbo.Secure30AWSMap' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

What am I doing wrong? Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744878/error-when-insert-into-linked-server) it seems like I cant use a 4 part name. However [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014242/create-database-on-remote-server-via-linked-server) sounds like it might be a workaround using an Exec statement. Is there a way to solve this without messing with the linked servers DDL though?

```
create table [name.mycompany.com].[DataAg].[dbo].[Secure30AWSMap]([servername] [nvarchar](50),[username] [nvarchar](50),[full_name][nvarchar](50),[awscoid][nvarchar](50))
```

Comment: i don't see a question here: the workaround is in your second link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `RPC` is configured `true` for linked server, it can help.

```
EXEC('create table [DataAg].[dbo].[Secure30AWSMap]([servername] [nvarchar](50),[username] [nvarchar](50),[full_name][nvarchar](50),[awscoid][nvarchar](50))') AT [name.mycompany.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your linked server and manually create the table and then try this.

```
  INSERT INTO [linkedserver].[database].[dbo].[table]
SELECT servername, username, fullname, awscoid
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE ID = userID;
```